# UIActionSheet doesn't show in view and screen goes dark

Tags: iphone

I have an app with tabs and navigation controllers.

Everything works great except a UIActionSheet.  I even have a UIAlertView taht shows fine in the same controller, but the action sheet doesn't show.  The screen goes dark, like it's showing, but no view.

Here's the relevant code:

```
UIActionSheet *actionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc]
initWithTitle:@"Erase the file?"
delegate:self
cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel"
destructiveButtonTitle:@"Clear List"
otherButtonTitles:nil];
actionSheet.actionSheetStyle = UIActionSheetStyleDefault;

[actionSheet showInView:[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow];

//[actionSheet showInView:self.view];

//MyAppDelegate* delegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
//[actionSheet showInView:delegate.tabBarController.view];

[actionSheet release];
```

The commented out code was the different ways of showing it that I've tried.

Any thoughts as to why this isn't working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't show it from the current keyWindow - show it from the actual tab bar with something like

```
[actionSheet showFromTabBar:delegate.tabBarController.tabBar];
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked.  I'll read into more as why this is.  I'll check the answer correct in 8 minutes when the site lets me.

Answer (score 2):

```
[actionSheet showInView:self.view.window];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try, this works perfectly:

```
UITextField *tempTextField;
UIActionSheet *myActionSheet;

- (IBAction) myDatePickerAction:(id)sender {

    tempTextField = (UITextField *)sender;  

    [(UITextField *)sender resignFirstResponder];

    myActionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:nil 
                                                              delegate:self

         cancelButtonTitle:nil

    destructiveButtonTitle:nil
                                                     otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [myActionSheet setActionSheetStyle:UIActionSheetStyleBlackTranslucent];

    UIDatePicker *theDatePicker = [[UIDatePicker alloc] init];
    theDatePicker.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerModeDate;
    CGRect datePickRect = theDatePicker.frame;
    datePickRect.size.height = 120;
    theDatePicker.frame = datePickRect;
    [theDatePicker addTarget:self action:@selector(setDateValue:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];

        [myActionSheet addSubview:theDatePicker];
        [theDatePicker release];

    UISegmentedControl *closeButton = [[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems:[NSArray arrayWithObject:@"Close"]];
        closeButton.momentary = YES; 
        CGRect closeButtonRect = closeButton.frame;
    closeButtonRect.size.width = 50;
    closeButtonRect.size.height = 30;
    closeButton.frame = closeButtonRect;
    closeButton.segmentedControlStyle = UISegmentedControlStyleBar;
    closeButton.tintColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    [closeButton addTarget:self action:@selector(dismissActionSheet:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    [myActionSheet addSubview:closeButton];
    [closeButton release];

    [myActionSheet showFromTabBar:appDelegate.tabBarController.tabBar];

    CGRect actionSheetRect = myActionSheet.bounds;
    actionSheetRect.size.height = 300;
    myActionSheet.bounds = actionSheetRect;

}

- (IBAction)setDateValue:(id)sender {
    NSDateFormatter *myDateFormatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
    [myDateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy"];

    NSLog(@"Formatted date1:%@",[myDateFormatter stringFromDate:[(UIDatePicker *)sender date]]);

    tempTextField.text = [myDateFormatter stringFromDate:[(UIDatePicker *)sender date]];
    tempTextField = nil;
}

- (IBAction)dismissActionSheet:(id)sender {
    [myActionSheet dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:YES];
    myActionSheet = nil;
    //[myActionSheet release]; 
//Do not release here. Just set to nil and release it in dealloc.
}
```